# Jenkins pipeline fails without error

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My Jenkins Pipeline fails even though no stage has an error:

[image]

The console log also shows no problems, but Build status: FAILURE.
Any tips on how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't able to see the image you uploaded. But you can roll over your mouse on the stages to see the logs in details. For example i usually have this issue during artifactory upload.For some reason artifactory upload stage failed, then it won't show anything in the log. But if i mouse over the different stages log i can get the exact problem. Give it a try

Comment: Could have been a checkout merge conflict or somewhere else. Easiest to look through full raw logs.

Comment: Thanks Samy, it was indeed a wrong path for a artifactory upload, without any trace of it in the log. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a wrong path for a artifactory upload, this let the pipeline silently fail.